# how to use Eval to grab column and row from Data frame

Tags: r

so I know I can do this to get the value in the row of TPDC that cooresponds to the row where CONC equals cmax:

```
tmax <- data$TPDC[which(data$CONC==cmax)]
```

but the TPDC and CONC are in variables.   which I would use like this:

```
data[eval(time.name)] or data[eval(conc.name)]
```

this works great but trying to do that in the first code above returns "undefined columns selected":

```
tmax <- data[eval(time.name)][which(data[eval(conc.name)]==cmax)]
```

even just doing causes the error

```
data['TPDC'][3]
```

So how does one accomplish selecting the column from a variable and subsetting to the row?  I'm sure there's something basic I'm just over looking..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok.. figured out how to do this.. use double [[ ]] so data[[eval(time.name)]] when using the single bracket I get a data.frame returned.. double brackets returns a list/vector like $ does..